# Update packages conflicting with core update

Tags: 8, composer

When updating drupal core via composer, you often get problems like:

> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for drupal/core 8.8.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.8.2].
>       - Conclusion: remove typo3/phar-stream-wrapper v2.1.4
>       ... (and so on)

How can you tackle these issues before updating core?

Comment: I've never had to do this. Even when converting an older project out of composer template to drupal/core-recommended, or composerizing an older 8.4 drush site to 8.7.11.

Comment: @Kevin I have had a couple rough updates between minors, and one site in particular had a lot of problems with 8.8.x that was only solved by deleting the lockfile and vendor.

Comment: Yeah weird, I wonder what the conditions are to reach that point. I hope its smoother going forward with the changes made to 8.8.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:
Thanks to the comment below from @mpdonadio below, it seems better to follow the official documentation right here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2700999#s-special-considerations-for-upgrading-to-drupal-880-and-later

```
composer update
git add composer.lock; git commit # Save the updates as a separate commit.
composer remove webflo/drupal-core-strict --no-update
composer remove drupal/core --no-update
composer require 'composer/installers:^1.7' --no-update
rm composer.lock
rm -rf vendor # Also helps avoid conflicts.
composer require drupal/core-recommended:^8.8 --update-with-dependencies
git add composer.json composer.lock; git commit -m "Update Drupal to 8.8.0 and use drupal/core-recommended instead of webflo/drupal-core-strict"
```

---

**Old answer**

First, make sure your composer version is not fixed (e.g. drupal/core:8.7.10):

```
composer require drupal/core:^8.7.10
```

This will update to its latest version (e.g. 8.7.11) but also makes sure you can progress later. To see which projects would cause problems, run:

```
composer prohibits drupal/core:8.8.0
```

This will result in a list:

```
typo3/phar-stream-wrapper (^3.1.3)
typo3/phar-stream-wrapper (but v2.1.4 is installed)
```

Then you can make sure you update the package:

```
composer require typo3/phar-stream-wrapper:^3.1.3
```

Then update like this:

```
 composer update drupal/core typo3/phar-stream-wrapper pear/archive_tar
```

Comment: Not sure if this really is the best approach.  It essentially lifts core dependencies to your root dependencies.  The 8.8 considerations in https://www.drupal.org/node/2700999 probably is the best approach.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me tot that documentation. I followed their commands and although it seems like not much has changed, it did add "drupal/core-recommended": "^8.8" to my dependencies.

Comment: One could say that having to delete your complete vendor file is rather 'dirty' and not really a clean upgrade...